# Need to create a seperate login page for different WordPress user levels

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I just need to write a page that slug is just 'login' for different user level with different login screen message.

Like: http://www.site-name.com/author/author-name/login/

From this i extract user Id from user name and show a different login screen message, but when i access this type URL wordpress shows 404 error page.

Please help me shortout the problem.

Comment: how will the user get to his/hers login screen? when it comes to your site it is not logged in, so how does he knows how to get to his own login address? or do you want to use this page after the user is logged in? and just redirect after login the user to his/hers own dashboard?

Comment: alex sums it up. If user is on a different computer, different IP address, then what. No cookies, no previous history to match, nothing. Then what...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think wordpress core libraries files / rules would allow you to use direct keyword like "login" in your url (Or As Per Your custom URL) , this is  due to fact to avoid  security threat concerns as Wordpress too uses this keyword for its internal purpose.

Anyways , there's still a solution to your desired functionality. You have to do custom codes & code some custom pages (Of LOgin  & post login landing ) . ALSO YOU CAN USE OTHER KEYWORDS LIKE "mylogin etc type..  for login url"

BUT DO KEEP IN MIND YOU MUST USE WORDPRESS CORE LOGIN SESSION MAINTAINANCE METHOD , so that correct entries are maintained in wp-users table in DB.

Hope you might get some usefull hint & get your work done.  even though if not, you can ask for further clarification. i will further deeply clarify it to you.

Comment: @alexalex thanks buddy.. :) but as of till now i avoid using such bcoz of conflict conviction..  thanks anyways